# How do I validate "final" string in custom NSFormatter

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsformatter

I am trying to validate a `NSTextField` through `NSFormatter`, my problem is I could validate the partial string and change the content of the cell as user type in with `isPartialStringValid:proposedSelectedRange:originalString:originalSelectedRange:errorDescription:`, but not the final, end string.

My problem is exactly like http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/123473-final-string-validation-in-custom-nsformatter.html . Is there any way that I can change the contents of a cell after validating the final string through a formatter?. For example "8/" in a textfield is valid as long as that cell has focus, once the cell looses focus it need's to be changed to "8/1".

I tried the solution mentioned in that thread, but changing the `object` in the `getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:` is not changing the text in the textfield.

P.S I want to do this within the `NSFormatter` methods. using `NSTextField` delegate is not an option for me.

Comment: The problem is, that you try to mix-up two different tasks:

While the user is writing in a text field the system wants to know, whether the input is valid. This is the task of the formatter.

But you want to complete the user input after the user has finished the editing. This is a different task. Use -textDidEndEditing: in your delegate to complete the user input.

If this is no option for you, there is no option for you. It is like: "I want to drive with my car on railroads. Using a train is no option for me."

Comment: What you're descripbing should work. Add your code to the question.

Comment: I finally got it to work, I was checking for the `errorDescription` to be non-nil before assigning the `object` value, removing that condition made it work. Apparently this method gets called multiple times (with or without the `errorDescription`) before changing the display text in the textfield.